# Join in Linq-To-Entities when no ID properties available

Tags: entity-framework, join, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

Given an `Order` entity with many `OrderItem`s, whereas each has a `Discount`, we are trying to retrieve all Orders with at least one discount that is more than `50%` by joining orders and order items.

There are a lot of articles about joining two entities in Linq-To-Entities, but they have all in common that they rely on the Foreign Key being exposed as a navigation property:

```
db.Orders.Join(
    db.OrderItems.Where(i => i.Discount > 50),
    o => o.Id,
    i => i.OrderId)
```

However, our `OrderItem`does not have an `OrderId` property. The `Order` has a `OrderItems` property to identify the relationship, the foreign key is managed by EF4.1 CodeFirst.

**Question:** Is there a way to perform a join by indicating `o => o.OrderItems` for identifying the relationship and have EF figure out which FK to use for the join?

---

On the background: We have tried to use `.Any` on the `OrderItems` but **DevArt dotConnect** has a breaking issue with that:

```
db.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderItems.Any(i => i.Discount > 50))
```

Comment: I'm afraid the "breaking issue" has broken your only chance to get the desired result - unless you have an `Order` navigation property on `OrderItem` or you are willing to use direct sql or DevArt takes care of the problem and proposes a workaround (does the last query with `.Count(...) > 0` instead of `.Any(...)` for example break as well?).

Comment: @Slauma: Thank you for the answer. Yes, unfortunately `.Count(...) > 0` breaks as well. In case you're interested in the details, it only starts to happen with 3 entities (`db.Customers.Where(c => c.Orders.Any(o => o.OrderItems.Any(i => i.Discount > 50)))`). The error message is "ORA-00904: "Extent1"."ID": invalid identifier, and the reason is that the same identifier is used twice in the outer and the inner of two nested select statements. That's certainly why replacing `Any(..)` by `Count(..) > 0` does not solve it.

Comment: @Slauma: BTW: Although your comment doesn't solve my issue, I'm afraid it answers my question of "Is there a way..." so it may be worthwhile to post it as an answer.